# Eliminar y agregar Clase a Lista con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

saludos.

He echo una pequen lista, la cual deseo agregar un efecto tipo :focus de seleccion con un background, se lo doy a través de una clase `is-active`. la finalidad es que cuando pulse otro elemento, elimine la clase del que la tenia y la agregue al nuevo, lo e echo con JQUERY pero me parece que debe haber alguna solución mas funcional o mejor escrita.

Agradezco posibles soluciones para acortar el código y expandir mis conocimientos. <3

```js
$(function(){
    $('.one-a').on('click', function(){
        $('.one-a').addClass('is-active');
        $('.one-b').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-c').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-d').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-e').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-f').removeClass('is-active');
    });
    $('.one-b').on('click', function(){
        $('.one-b').addClass('is-active');
        $('.one-a').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-c').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-d').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-e').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-f').removeClass('is-active');
    });
    $('.one-c').on('click', function(){
        $('.one-c').addClass('is-active');
        $('.one-a').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-b').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-d').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-e').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-f').removeClass('is-active');
    });
    $('.one-d').on('click', function(){
        $('.one-d').addClass('is-active');
        $('.one-a').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-b').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-c').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-e').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-f').removeClass('is-active');
    });
    $('.one-e').on('click', function(){
        $('.one-e').addClass('is-active');
        $('.one-a').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-b').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-c').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-d').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-f').removeClass('is-active');
    });
    $('.one-f').on('click', function(){
        $('.one-f').addClass('is-active');
        $('.one-a').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-b').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-c').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-d').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.one-e').removeClass('is-active');
    });
});
```

```css
.is-active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="one-a is-active"><a>item a</a></li>
    <li class="one-b"><a>item b</a></li>
    <li class="one-c"><a>item c</a></li>
    <li class="one-d"><a>item d</a></li>
    <li class="one-e"><a>item e</a></li>
    <li class="one-f"><a>item f</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: por que no dejas la misma clase? para el elemento `li`?, asi podrias hacerlo corto después el cambio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer mucho mas sencillo asi:

```js
$(function(){
    $('li').on('click', function(){
       $(".is-active").removeClass("is-active");
       $(this).addClass("is-active");
    });
});
```

```css
.is-active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="one-a is-active"><a>item a</a></li>
    <li class="one-b"><a>item b</a></li>
    <li class="one-c"><a>item c</a></li>
    <li class="one-d"><a>item d</a></li>
    <li class="one-e"><a>item e</a></li>
    <li class="one-f"><a>item f</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: super bien..... excellente, sabia que deberia de haber una mejor respuesta pero ni idea como, estoy empezando. :) gracias amigo!

Comment: De nada Gabriela, para eso estamos

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera si tienes mas elementos `li` en la vista

```js
$(".one").click(function(){
  
  $(this).addClass('is-active');
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('is-active');
  
});
```

```css
.is-active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="one is-active"><a>item a</a></li>
    <li class="one"><a>item b</a></li>
    <li class="one"><a>item c</a></li>
    <li class="one"><a>item d</a></li>
    <li class="one"><a>item e</a></li>
    <li class="one"><a>item f</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Lo que hace el código arriba es que al hacer click sobre si mismo, o sea la clase "one" , se agrega la clase `is-active` y después con la propiedad `siblings` de jquery selecciono los **"hermanos"** del elemento que están dentro de la etiqueta **padre** `lu` y les remuevo la clase **"is-active"**

Comment: gracias por la explicación también que funciona a la perfección, aprendiendo super, `siblings` agregada a mis practicas diarias.

Comment: de nada @Gabriela toda ayuda siempre viene bien.